# How to catch all exceptions in web config from all controllers c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, exception, web-config, try-catch

We're using MVC Structure and have multiple c# controllers, is it possible to catch them all thru web.config? instead of adding a catch statement to all controller methods?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own base controller and handle the exceptions in the `OnException` event.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
       // to do : Log the exception (filterContext.Exception)
       // and redirect / return error view
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        // If the exception occurred in an ajax call. Send a json response back
        // (you need to parse this and display to user as needed at client side)
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]
                                                          =="XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new { Error = true, Message = filterContext.Exception.Message }
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500; // Set as needed
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error.cshtml" }; 
            //Assuming the view exists in the "~/Views/Shared" folder
        }
    }
}
```

For non ajax requests, it will render the `Error.cshtml` to the user. If you want to do a redirect (a new GET call) to your `Error` action method instead of showing `Error.cshtml`, you can replace the `ViewResult` with a `RedirectToRouteResult`.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {
                                               {"controller", "Home"}, {"action", "Error"}
                                              };
```

Now have your other controllers inherit from this

```
public class HomeController : BaseController 
{
   public ActionResult Die()
   {
      throw new Exception("Bad code!");
   }
}
public class ProductsController : BaseController 
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var arr =new int[2];
       var thisShouldCrash = arr[10];
       return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this. @shyju